# Using fragment more than one time with new values with backstack maintain

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am making an app using **sliding menu** and **tab** in bottom...whole app is **fragment** based..I am facing some problem that is I am using **fragment A** then click on a button and go to **fragment B**,in **Fragment B** there is a button on clicking on this button the **fragment A** will update with new values..and so on

means switching from A->B should be occur..but backstack should also be mantain..

Here is my code for **BackStack**:

```
public static void goToFragmentWithBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
    Fragment tmp = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getName());
    if (tmp != null && tmp.isVisible())
        return;

    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
    currentTag = fragment.getClass().getName();
}
```

Here I am using only this method to go to the next fragment. And the back button is already mantained by activity's backpressed. **When I use this method and again call the Fragment A(which is already in the container) it is not called**...and if I use **gotoFragment** method it is called but old **Fragment A is destroyed**(blank screen will occur).Here is my **gotoFragment** Method:

```
public static void goToFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    Fragment tmp = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getName());
    if (tmp != null && tmp.isVisible())
        return;

    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
    currentTag = fragment.getClass().getName();
    Log.d("Trong", "BackPressedcurrentTag " + currentTag);
}
```

I have used this concept to reused the used fragment : [Android - Instantiate a Fragment multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677178/android-instantiate-a-fragment-multiple-times)

But it is not helped.Let me clear my problem again:

**I want to use a used fragment again and again in a container and all the fragments should be also call on back pressed**

The flow should be something like this : A->B->A->B->A  AND on backpressed:  A<-B<-A<-B<-A 
(Every time A will have new values ,new data)

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

The new instances of fragment ..I have made is something like this:

```
    public static FollowerFragment newInstance() {
    return new FollowerFragment(null,null,null);
}

public static Fragment newInstance(String cat_id,String status,String id) {
    return new FollowerFragment(cat_id,status,id);
}
public FollowerFragment(String cat_id,String status,String id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.str_status=cat_id;
    this.counter = status;
    this.user_id = id;

}
```

Comment: Create a new instance of each fragment. It looks like you're using 1 of each and switching back and forth

Comment: thanks for your reply but I have switching between them for infinite times(as the users wants) then in that case I have to make  many instances..but if you think that it is possible then please explain me by code..

Comment: You're putting too much thought into this, it's really not that hard. You don't need to keep track of the backstack if you let it handle itself. All you need to do is create new instances of whatever fragment and replace current with new. I also am not capable of explaining you  and your existence as a human in code(yet!), sorry

Comment: As I'm sure to expect you're creating a single one and trying to reuse it, which is fine, but you're also expecting old data to remain in your recycled fragment on the backstack. Someone correct me if I'm wing, but that doesn't seem logical.

Comment: Sir please share any code for that..I will try it

Comment: Your edit doesn't show you making any new instances. It shows that you simply have a `newInstance` method for your fragment... I will try to explain in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically an extended comment to better help OP understand what needs to be done.

Ok, you have `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`.
Within `FragmentA` you replace your container with a **new** `FragmentB`.
From `FragmentB` you want to display `FragmentA` again, but with new data, but you're also wanting to keep the original fragment with the old data in the backstack. It doesn't work like that.

The following is a very simplified example of the direction you should be going to achieve your goal.

Since you're wanting to display different information on each fragment, your constructor for each fragment should include a way for you to tell it what should be displayed, for example:

```
public class FragmentA{
    String mText;
    public FragmentA(String text){
        mText = text;
    }
}
```

Now, when you need to create a new `FragmentA` from within `FragmentB` or wherever, you need only do something such as, and using your own methods:

```
goToFragmentWithBackStack(new FragmentA("this is the new data"));
```

Again, this is simply a basic example of what you should be doing, instead of recycling old fragments with new data. You most likely can't copy/paste this and expect it to work, but it gives you an idea of what you'll need to do.

Comment: I have tried this ..but it is not called when again repeated call on the previous fragment (which already exist in stack) .I have changed my new instance with your suggestion ..but it is not working ...

Comment: Probably because you're trying to control the backstsck improperly. Search on how to properly control backstack on back pressed. Your definitely trying too hard

Comment: I have tried this again with some modifications..when I used   ft.add..  in goToFragmentWithBackStack then it is not called when old fragment is need to regenrate..and when I use ft.replace..  in goToFragmentWithBackStack then the old fragments become black when I back pressed.

Comment: Again, there is no need for you to be handling the backstack.

Comment: glad it helped..I have remove the remove fragment functionality from the onBackPressed of the parent activity and it is working ..thanks a lot..you saved my life.. :)

Comment: Hello sir..I am observing that if I have used  ft.add in place of ft.replace it will not work...but if I have used ft.replace it will work...but according to my need I have to use ft.add ..but with ft.add and with your solution it is not working..can you help me to resolve this...

Comment: @userAndroid... WTF did you just say?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void goToFragmentWithBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
    Fragment tmp = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getName());
    if (tmp != null && tmp.isVisible())
        return;

    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
//  ft.addToBackStack(null);
//  you are suppose to pass string as the parameter that will be unique to identity your
//   fragment on the backstack
    ft.commit();
    currentTag = fragment.getClass().getName();
}
```

If you choose to take advantage of the back stack for fragments, This tag should be an
appropriate string name that represents the state of the fragments at the time of the
transaction. You will be able to interrogate the back stack in code using the tag value to
delete entries, as well as pop entries off. You will want meaningful tags on these
transactions to be able to find the appropriate ones later.

try to generate unique string everytime you make a fragment transction with backstack

```
pubic static int mCount = 0 ;
pubic static String mFragmentTag = "frag_tag_" ;

     public static void goToFragmentWithBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
            Fragment tmp = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getName());
            if (tmp != null && tmp.isVisible())
                return;

            ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.addToBackStack(mFragmentTag+mCount);
            mCount+=1;
        //  you are suppose to pass string as the parameter that will be unique to identity your
        //   fragment on the backstack
            ft.commit();
            currentTag = fragment.getClass().getName();
        }
```